# Requesting experts to assist on other question on topic

Tags: discussion, documentation

**Context:** Some documentation topics like design-patterns have pending approvals regarding the content in the topic for a long time. Only 69 people have been awarded bronze tag. In this scenario, is it OK to contact one or two of these 69 people on attend review of these topics by leaving a comment in one of the questions answered by that expert. The only problem I can see here is comment is not related to the question.

Content of comment :

> Hi SomeX, on a different note , can you help others in reviewig the documentation content in design-patterns topic? Only 69 people have been awarded bronze badge for this topic and you are one of them.

Comment: There are more cases where we could use some help (close votes/down votes/delete votes) and if this was allowed it would set a precedent for others.

Comment: *"The only problem I can see here is comment is not related to the question."* Really? You can't see any problem with nagging other people and making demands about how they spend their time? If this is implemented, the next feature request is going to be "Ability to hand in my bronze badge to escape incessant pestering."

Comment: I am not looking at any feature implementation. I am looking for leaving a comment in a question.

Comment: @ravjndra what cody is saying is that if we let you ping ppl for stuff like that, people will try to make a fearure request to "cancel" their badge, just to gain some peace of mind

Comment: Ok understood the problem now . Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Comments like *Thanks*, *You're welcome*, *Vote on my questions!*, or *Upvote my answers please* are really annoying as many Stack Overflow users have notifications switched on on their smartphones. Would a person notified with a vote request be happy after being called from the couch, where he was watching a movie, drinking wine with his wife?

Stack Overflow notifications are used to inform user that someone has taken an action that he expects somehow. Not to get in touch with another user. As someone mentioned above, if we allowed such commenting, good users would be permanently flooded by recruitment companies trying to get in touch with programmers.

Answer (score 13):

Please don't.

If you've been paying any attention to the discussions about Documentation that occurred here on Meta, you know that quite a few experts have made the *conscious decision to not participate in Documentation*. The last thing they need is being nagged to participate.

Answer (score 5):

It's unlikely for Stack Overflow to suddenly allow for notifications to appear which a user has not explicitly opted in for, especially to target specific users (even if it's not by name, but rather by the fact that they have a bronze badge).

However, I wonder if this speaks more to a point of there not being enough active participants in the tag you're trying to get reviewed for there to be sufficient activity and clean-up.

Comment: *recruiting* might be appropriate when a user is in a chat room.